# Multiple typed variables in one line in Julia

Tags: types, syntax, julia

Is it possible to define multiple variables with type information in a single line in Julia v0.5+? One can define untyped variables, like so (let's assume the variables are within some function),

```
x1, x2 = 0.01, 0.5
```

but adding type information,

```
local x1 :: Float64, x2 :: Float64 = 0.01, 0.5
```

fails with an `invalid syntax in "local" declaration` error. Am I doing something wrong, or is this kind of syntax not supported at all? TIA.

Comment: Why do you want to add the type information at all. It makes the code noisy and hard to read, without adding anything.

Comment: Mostly just for experimenting with factors that could affect code performance.

Comment: Right, my point is that these annotations don't affect performance at all (unless you put a different type in the annotation than in the literal value).

Comment: Fair enough, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`local` isn't needed in most situations, such as a plain function at top-level.

```
julia> function f()
           x1::Float64, x2::Float64 = 1, 5
           x1, x2
       end
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f()
(1.0,5.0)
```

Where `local` is needed (that is, where the name would otherwise be bound to an outer function), this syntax won't work as far as I know. See [#7314](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/7314).

Comment: Thanks, although it appears that the old `x :: T` type declaration syntax has been deprecated as of v0.5.0: [#16071](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/16071)

Comment: @AretsPaeglis That [has not been deprecated](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/pull/17445). It is only a lone `x::T` local (that is, without the RHS) that has been deprecated.

Comment: [This](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/16071#issuecomment-215984705) comment seemed to suggest otherwise but, having tested a few examples, I see your point. Thanks.